# VBA Find function not working with variable

Tags: vba, variables, excel, find

I am creating a sheet that needs the application to search excel sheet for a value that is saved in a variable. 
I am using the ".Find" function for this.

My problem is that the value being searched for can not be found while it is stored in a variable name although it works when i input an actual value.

For example:

this works

```
Dim cellersd, celltid, ersdcol, tidcol
Set cellersd = book.Worksheets(mon & yer).Range("5:5").Find("28/08/2013")
Set celltid = book.Worksheets(mon1 & yer1).Range("5:5").Find("30/09/2013")

If cellersd Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "not found"
Else
MsgBox cellersd.Column
End If

If celltid Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "not found"
Else
MsgBox celltid.Column
End If
```

this doesnt work

```
rsd = Worksheets("workload").Range("p4").Value
tid = Worksheets("workload").Range("p3").Value
...

Dim cellersd, celltid, ersdcol, tidcol
Set cellersd = book.Worksheets(mon & yer).Range("5:5").Find(rsd)
Set celltid = book.Worksheets(mon1 & yer1).Range("5:5").Find(tid)

If cellersd Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "not found"
Else
MsgBox cellersd.Column
End If

If celltid Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "not found"
Else
MsgBox celltid.Column
End If
```

The ... in the code just shows that i have other codes inbetween which perform different actions

Can you spot my error?
i am also open to suggestions on other search methods that could equally work. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to Find a string variable or a Date variable??

Comment: After this line `tid = Worksheets("workload").Range("p3").Value`, type this and tell me what do you get `Msgbox rsd & " and " & len(rsd)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout i got the lenght of the characters in the date

Comment: @Gary'sStudent its a date variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try

```
rsd = Worksheets("workload").Range("p4").Text
tid = Worksheets("workload").Range("p3").Text
```

or if you wish to keep `.Value` or `.Text` does not work you chould try to convert to string:

```
rsd = str(rsd)
tid = str(tid)
```

I believe the `.Value` returns a date and not a string. and the working code is using a string.

Answer (score 1):

This Should work

Use `What:=rsd` if it's variable, use `What:="something"` if it's exact word between "".

If you need find variable from variable then use:

```
Set find1 = variable1.Find(What:=variable2, LookIn:=xlValues)

'Both work 
rsd = Worksheets("workload").Range("P4")
tid = Sheets("workload").Range("P3")
...

Dim ersdcol, tidcol
Dim cellersd As Object
Dim celltid As Object

Set cellersd = Sheets("mon & yer").Range("5:5").Find(What:=rsd, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set celltid = Sheets("mon1 & yer1").Range("5:5").Find(What:=tid, LookIn:=xlValues)


If cellersd Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "not found"
Else
MsgBox cellersd.Column
End If

If celltid Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "not found"
Else
MsgBox celltid.Column
End If
```

Comment: Why does it work?  Explain.  Also, please format your post so that it is properly code indented.  Check out this post for more details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks